# @font-face not working in firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I have use this font face code on server but it's not working in Mozilla and Internet Explorer.

```
  font-family: 'halvettcondensedregular';
  src: url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.eot');
  src: url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.svg#halvettcondensedregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

Comment: might be need to define font MIME TYPE in config file.

Comment: is font path is correct? is it working in other browsers?

Comment: could you provide a link to your site?

Comment: http://oscitasthemes.com/

Comment: Yes @kiran It's Working in Chrome.

Comment: @kheema  Can you please describe in detail how i do this.

Comment: In Firefox, I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://oscitasthemes.oscitaswebsoluti.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/edd-oscthemes/css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.woff. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.` Might be worth reading this : http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/

Comment: custom font won't display on browser until you define them in .htaccess file or in IIS server. All latest browser have support for font type `woff`. MIME Type for Woff `application/x-font-woff`

Comment: @punitsharma I hope you will satisfy with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom font won't display on browser until you define them in `.htaccess` file or in `IIS server`.

To define the font `MIME Type` for `woff` type use `application/x-font-woff`.
same apply for other font format as well.

> Note: All latest browser have support for font type `woff`.

**UPDATE:**

Add like this in .htaccess file

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

Comment: does this answer helps you? if yes then you may accept the answer.

Comment: @kheemapandy i have define <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://oscitasthemes.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch> in .htaccess but it's doesn't work.

Comment: how did you define in .htacess file?

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mydomain.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

Comment: I use IIS server never use .htaccess file . let me find out a solution

Comment: have a look at my updated answer. let me know if its works now.

Comment: Sorry i forget to close this question ...i use your updated answer but still not working ... now i have use new font-face...

Comment: that's really strange why its not working in your case. normally this the procedure to work with custom fonts.

Comment: Sorry @kheema but don't know why its not working... :(

Comment: yes Now I have use same custom web font and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for giveing me your valuable time... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `local('☺')` for IE.

I can't see why firefox should not work. Could you try:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'halvettcondensedregular';
        src: url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.eot');
        src: local('☺'), 
            url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
            url('css/fonts/halvettcondensed-webfont.svg#iefix') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```